# Transfer recording from Virgin TIVO box to HUMAX Aura Android TV 4K Freeview Recorder

Tags: android-tv, video-recording

We are replacing Virgin Media with a basic Internet connection and a Humax Aura Android TV 4K Freeview Play Recorder.   How can we transfer the recordings we have saved on our Virgin box?

Comment: Sorry but this question is mainly about exporting recordings from a non-Android system, which is AFAIK locked in a way that you can not even transfer something from one TIVO to new TIVO box, so why do you think exporting to an Android box may be possible?

Comment: @Robert TIVO seems to have an Android app for downloading programs to watch while away from home.

Comment: Then you should try to install that app on your HUMAX and download all recordings.

Comment: @robert I don't get the box until Monday and don't know if all Android apps work in all Android devices.  Also don't know if the TIVO app works with a Virgin TIVO.  The are also a handful of opening source apps that claim to connect to both TiVo and other media players.

Answer (score 1):

**At present this is a collection of my notes, hopefully it will become an answer that is useful to other people.**

The Virgin TIVO box connects to the Virgin network with a dedicated coaxial connection and runs IP back to the Virgin servers separate from the Virgin internet service.   There is an ethernet socket in the back of the Virgin box.

I can't see any Wi-Fi settings on the Virgin menu, hence it looks like our box is too old to have WiFi.   I have enabled remove control of the box over the local network on the setup/network menu of the Virgin box.

Plugged in either net cable, can ping IP address shown on Virgin box network connection info page.

---

Where can I find my media access key for my Virgin Media TiVo box?

Your media access key (MAK) is a code which identifies your TiVo box. If you have more than one box, each will have a unique MAK to identify it on your Virgin Media broadband network.

To find your MAK:

1. Using TiVo, go to Home > Help & Settings > System Info > Media Access Key
2. Enter your TV PIN when prompted - if you haven't set a TV PIN the default is 1234
3. You should see your 10-digit MAK in the middle of the screen

---

Install TiVo Desktop on PC

---

Seems Virgin TiVo box does not use the same networking as other TiVo boxes.